# Spring jUnit Testing - either can not autowire or can not find appContext.xml

Tags: spring, junit, junit4, spring-test

I am unittesting a spring based application atm. 
First the problem is, that if I haven't started the app once on a server the unittests all fail.
If I do start the app on the server first (and stop it), my unit tests are working.

Without starting the server I get the following error:

```
... java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

My Unit test is defined as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional
public class InventoryControllerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;

    private AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        handlerAdapter = applicationContext
            .getBean(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.class);
}
    //... tests
}
```

So like I said, if I've started the app once before, everything works fine.

So I changed the configuration location to 
    locations = { "classpath/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml" })
But without effort, same exception as named above.

The only way to get further is this location:
    locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext-test.xml" })
Then I get this exception:
    No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

But that's confusing, because I definetly have a datasource in my test context file:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true" />
    <property name="username" value="some" />
    <property name="password" value="some" />
</bean>
```

### EIDT 2

After recognizing, that the problem is RunWith(...) and extending the spring class at the same time and removing all wildcards from the location path. I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'persistenceUnitTest' found
... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'persistenceUnitTest' found
... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'persistenceUnitTest' found)
... 47 more
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to test? - we unit test our spring controllers outside of the application context.

Comment: Is this a maven project, and you use eclipse?

Comment: @Ralph : Yes
@ Bedwyr: Because I want to check if the dispatcher is working properly. It's a kind of integrationTest where I need the context for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a `:` between `classpath` and Path, as well as the path must not start with `/`. So the correct syntax would be:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml" })
```

or a bit shorter form

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml")
```

---

An other problem, found by your self is that you should use `@ContextConfiguration` OR `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests`. Here is the accoding note from Java Doc of `AbstractTransactonalJUnit4SpringContextTests`

>
Note: this class serves only as a convenience for extension. If you do not
 wish for your test classes to be tied to a Spring-specific class hierarchy,
 you may configure your own custom test classes by using
 {@link SpringJUnit4ClassRunner}, {@link ContextConfiguration
 @ContextConfiguration}, {@link TestExecutionListeners
 @TestExecutionListeners}, {@link Transactional @Transactional},
 etc.

---

The starting problem:
Eclipse does not copy the resources from `src\test\resources` to the target directory. So you need one tool or something that do this for you. You have found one way: starting the application. A second one would be running `maven test` from eclipse.

Comment: Oh sorry, that came because I didn't copy it, just a typo.
But it seems that 
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
is in conflict with:
AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
Maybe u should use either of them.
Because now I am getting an 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'persistenceUnitTest' found
although I do have on in my persistence.xml

Comment: Ok thanks, but it doesn't make any difference:
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml"})
public class InventoryControllerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
throws the FileNotFoundException
if I do it via the classpath*:... I'll get an Exception : No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency

Comment: Alexander: did you tryed the path in the way I recommended? classpath, ":", without "*" and without "/"

Comment: And If the exception still occures, please print the full stack trace

Comment: Yes I tried "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-test.xml" and it is working but then I'll get the exception mentioned in my first comment:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'persistenceUnitTest' found, although I do have a persistence xml with the specified persistenceUnitTest

Comment: Where is your persistence.xml located? (complete path from project root)

Comment: It's in src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml but src/main/resources is declared as source folder in eclipse...

Comment: @Alexander: that is ok, and that eclipse take it as a source folder is correct. Is the persistence.xml copied to the target?

Comment: Hmm I don't know where to check that exactly, but it seems to, because running works fine. Can't find any copy in my pom.xml...

Comment: It's very confusing, adding the persistence.xml to the META-INF/spring/ folder would solve the problem, but I really want to know how to solve the problem without moving persistence.xml to another directory.
It seems that something fails during the file copy phase...

Comment: @Alexander: please post the entity manager factory declaration.

Comment: Okay I think it works. After deleting all folders in the target and doing a clean build in eclipse the unit tests walk through (in eclipse and in the console via mvn test)
Great grat thanks for your help Ralph!